# How can I change the default music player?

Tags: mp3, mp3-player

Using Ubuntu 11.10.  I have MP3 files.  When I double-click an MP3 file, I would like VLC to open (not Banshee).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Right-click an MP3 file, and from the menu select “Properties”.

In the window that appears, go to the “Open With” tab and select VLC. Click the “Set As Default” button to set VLC as the default player.

You might also want to set the default player in the sound menu:

- [How do I change the Sound Menu's default music player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37158/how-do-i-change-the-sound-menus-default-music-player)

Answer (score 3):

Right click the file and choose properties. In the dialog that appears, select Opens with... You can choose which apps to use to open different files.