# How to make the GNOME Music Player Client (GMPC) my prefered ubuntu music player application?

Tags: unity, music, default-programs, music-player

How can make GMPC my default music program and *integrate it with the unity top-bar* just as rhythmbox or Banshee?

Thank you,
Pedro

Comment: possible duplicate -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/68046/how-can-i-change-the-default-music-player

Comment: It is not a dupplicate! I want to be able to use the unity musicplayer controls!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GMPC is just a client to underlying MPD

You can integrate MPD to Unity Sound Menu following this instructions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:torkvemada/torkvemada
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpd-sound-menu
```

then add it in start-up applications like `mpd-sound-menu`

Answer (score 0):

mpd is not something like mplayer. Its a music player daemon. You have to choose a folder to add songs to its library.

You cannot use mpd to play a single file. If you want to play a file, first you have to add it to the library and then update the database & then add that file to the current playlist.
gmpc is just a GUI client to control that daemon.

So, its mpd thats doing the work, NOT gmpc.

Comment: That's right. Though, it doesn't answer my question.