# How to Change the music player in the Unity Panel - The Default is Banshee

Tags: default-programs, music-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the Sound Menu's default music player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37158/how-do-i-change-the-sound-menus-default-music-player)

From what I know, A music player requires an extension with a MPRIS2 spec to be listed in the drop down menu of the Ubuntu 11.10 Unity Panel Sound Applet.

The default player (for music files) *and* the default music player listed in the Unity Panel Sound Applet's drop down menu is both Banshee.

Setting the default mp3 player does not change the default music player in the Unity Panel drop down menu, since the selected default music player requires the MPRIS2 extension. I'm not sure whether applications such as QMMP, Audicious and VLC have these extensions.

Are there any methods to write a MPRIS2 spec for any given music player so that you can add it to the Unity Panel, or are we completely dependent on the developers of the music players to provide MPRIS2 spec extensions?